# Meteor iron router to #each my result

Tags: meteor

I can use the data: element of this.route to render a template with a findOne search using {{name}} in my html template. However if I return an array of objects using the find().fetch() function no {{name}} data is rendered because I need to use the {{#each}} in my html but what would my {{#each reference}} be? If I use the variable name I'm returning this doesn't work?

Comment: I've considered creating a template helper but seems odd considering I can do this without a helper using a single document in the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it makes things clearer to you, you can use an object in the data function to name what you're returning (I'm not a big fan of `{{#each this}}` but it is perfectly valid).

```
data:function(){
  // instead of "return Players.find();" return an object with
  // a single property to name our list of players :
  return {
    players:Players.find()
  };
}
```

Then in your template you'll be able to reference the players property from the current data context :

```
{{#each players}}
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the code. I find the meteor documentation quite lacking so far so this really helps. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{#each .}}` or `{{each this}}`